# Multiple windows in one page for bookmarks

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-flex, html, xul

I want a single online web page for my bookmarks. The page should include small windows which opens the following pages:

Fizy, Facebook, Guardian.

There should also be a button for adding a new window with an URL text input.

Here's an illustration of how the page should look: http://i54.tinypic.com/2hrkb48.jpg

I've built a version of this at http://bit.ly/heqEd1, but as you may see, it uses iframes under javascript windows, which can not open frame-breaking sites (like fizy.com), or Facebook.

I'll make the research and but I am not sure how to proceed. Any solution will be accepted, like HTML5, XUL, Flex, AJAX or others. A solution with a local installation(like a Firefox extension) is not preferred, but still be ok.

Note: Piro Sakura has built a Firefox extension called split-browser. There's an element of the project called "subbrowser". An AJAX window that can show a subbrowser MAY solve the problem. I know the page will only be available from Firefox, but that is ok. (Again, a solution without an installation is preferred)

Any suggestions? How should I proceed? What should I learn? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, One solution would be to proxy everything and remove the frame breaking javascript code on the fly but I'm not sure how to do it ?

Comment: Yeah, that would solve it, but it is illegal

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple draggable windows in FLEX same as you have in you app

Please check sample as Starting point [Movable/Draggable window](http://alekkus.com/blog/2009/01/flex-tutorial-movable-draggable-window/) and its [demo](http://alekkus.com/flex3/draggable_window.html)

also u knows JS-DESKTOP lib with little customization to achieve that one of them are
[jsdesk](http://www.jsdesk.com/)

[sonspring](http://desktop.sonspring.com/)-JQuery based

also you can do this using

Hopes that helps

Comment: I don't think it would work with Flex since the HTML component is only for Air

Comment: I would like to try FLEX or AIR, but I think they also use iframes for the external site content. I am not looking for it.

Comment: @levtrocki, actually, Air has it's own built in, Webkit based browser in it (no iFrame, but it can render them).  You could definitely do this in Air using several 'windows'.  [Look here](http://amrkamel.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/web-browser-using-adobe-air/) for a very simple (and a bit outdated) example implementation of a browser made in Air

Comment: Can it be run in any browser, I mean without a local installation. Is it a good browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a Javascript with iFrames to do this.  I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, but it should be possible.  As for which framework you'll use, it's up to you, but there will be a lot of custom code needed to implement this.

Comment: iframes don't work with framebreaking sites, that's why I wrote down fizy.com. If you've read my question, I already have a version with javascript with iframes. That's not I am looking for.